# Layperson wondering about The power within one protium atom (1H) or H

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, vacuum

Within 1 hydrogen atom (1H) protium we have 1 electron
the half life of this stable isotope is 10 to the 34th power years.
It can fuse into Helium if 4 atoms fuse when the Coulomb force is overcome and the specific pressures of the Gamow Window are met.

But otherwise it wont interact with itself.

So the questions I have are
1 atom at rest will have X amount of total energy measured in is it Giga-electron Volts? Mev? ev?

Is there any means to find what energy is in that same radius of spacetime
and is that energy more or less? ( one hydrogen atom's worth of "empty" space)
Contains orders of magnitude more/less energy than the matter itself?

and say that atom exists from the big bang to to to the 34th power years,
what of all the energy of the electron moving in the shell for that amount of time? isn't that a massive amount of kinetic energy over billions of years?
But if you examine it on day one or day 500 quintzillion it has the same energy?

If you account for all the spin and orbiting and what not could the energy within matter at rest, over billions of years be any part of the "missing mass" attributed to dark energy, dark matter and such. I'm to understand electrons are whizzing around in their shells right? You cannot know the speed or position simultaneously, but without decaying or jumping orbitals, is not the energy of a single electron then just massive? Just staying in it's lane for billions of years, what becomes of all that motion?

Answer (score 0):

The moon is going around the earth for millions of years. Its current kinetic energy is classically $1/2mv^2$, by definition, though it has been turning around the earth for so long. It does not need extra energy to stay in its orbit, to first order ( there are tides etc, but that is a different story)

You are trying to understand quantum mechanical behaviors using your lay person's "knowledge" of classical mechanics.

One of the reasons quantum mechanics was invented was exactly because classical mechanics of electrons running around nuclei is "no go". In contrast to gravitation, the charged electron would radiate away photons and eventually would  drop on the proton neutralizing it,  and no atom would exist.

So the electrons in hydrogen are not running around in orbits. They exist in orbitals, which are probability loci , [here are the hydrogen atom locations](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) where an electron may be found, depending on the energy level it occupies.

[image]

If one does not disturb the hydrogen atom it is stable, the electron in a probable point, not orbiting in circles,the atom quite stable.

Dark matter and dark energy still come from classical physics calculations. If there is a quantum mechanical explanation it will have to come from quantization of gravity, which is a guess in effective theories for cosmological models, at present, as gravity has not yet been definitively quantized.